# DataTables from AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, promise

I can populate a data table just fine with static data. But when I retrieve data from an AJAX and want to implement it into the table, I cannot seem to figure it out.

Here is first my JSFiddle that works perfectly with static data, https://jsfiddle.net/L0287qeu/.

Here is my current code for my HTML table that works perfectly after making the call to retrieve/load the data I want to populate.

```
    <html>
<head>
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title><strong>X, Y, & Z Deliverables</strong></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <h4 class="text-center">X, Y, & Z Deliverables</h4>
        <table class = "display">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Program</th>
                <th>Deliverable</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Approved</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
    </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
function loadData(source, url) {
  return fetch(url, { headers: { accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" } }) // make request
    .then((r) => {
      if (!r.ok) throw new Error("Failed: " + url);  // Check for errors
      return r.json();  // parse JSON
    })
    .then((data) => data.d.results) // unwrap to get results array
    .then((results) => {
      results.forEach((r) => (r.source = source)); // add source to each item
      return results;
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  Promise.all([
    loadData("XDeliverables", "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('XDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes"),
    loadData("YDeliverables", "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('YDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes"),
    loadData("ZDeliverables", "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ZDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes"),
  ])
    .then(([r1, r2, r3]) => {
      const objItems = r1.concat(r2,r3);
      var tableContent =
        '<table id="deliverablesTable" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Program</strong></td>' +
        "<td><strong>To</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Approved</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Notes</strong></td>" +
        "</tr></thead><tbody>";

      for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
      }
      $(tableContent).appendTo("#deliverables").DataTable();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert("Error: " + err);
      console.error(err);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't spot anything horribly wrong though you might like to make sure the HTML is well formed with `</tbody></table>`. You will also need to call `.DataTable()` on the appended table, eg `$(tableContent).appendTo("#deliverables").DataTable(...);`.

Comment: Check out my most recent edit. Sharepoint is saying $ is not defined, and all that appears after the error window is the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of populating Datatables with Ajax. In the HTML the table is defined as:

```
<table ID=tblClients><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Intake Date</th><th>Counselor</th></tr></thead></table>
```

Then in the document.ready function this code initializes the Datatable:

```
dtClients = $('#tblClients').DataTable({
  ajax: 'nwcs.php?proc=get_clients',
  dom: 'iftp',
  paging: true,
  pageLength: 15,
  pagingType : 'full_numbers',
  select: {style: 'single'}
});
```

The data returned from PHP is JSON, which DataTables requires. It looks like this:

```
{"data":[["Laura Jessup","02/22/2020","Michelle Putnam"],["Jackie McCord","02/24/2020","Paula Curran"],["Gary Shafer","02/25/2020","Paula Curran"]]}
```

Comment: For the ajax request it looks like you're pulling from a PHP file, mine does not pull from a file. This is where I am lost

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting your data. Also, you didn't say what happens when you try, whether there's an error message, etc. More information might be helpful. You should probably post this on the Datatables forum.

Comment: I am pulling from a sharepoint list/multiple. How do I get the php?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about sharepoint so I can't help you with that. You need to somehow get it to return JSON in the format expected by Datatables.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it. To render the datatable as such, the content has to be rendered by the browser first.

The difference between your working JSFiddle and your non-working code is that in the non-working code, the table with id `deliverablesTable` is part of the string `tableContent` and not rendered at the time you call `.DataTable()` whereas in your working example with static data, the table `example` is already defined in the HTML part and therefore already rendered.

Please find code sample below. I replaced your Ajax Calls with static data for demonstration purposes, but it will work the same way once you migrated the most important changes (commented as such)

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title><strong>X, DAR-Q, & Z Deliverables</strong></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <h4 class="text-center">X, DAR-Q, & Z Deliverables</h4>
        <table class = "display">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Program</th>
                <th>Deliverable</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Approved</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- RESERVE DIV FOR HOLDING THE DATA TABLE -->
    <div id="data" class="container">
    </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>

      const objItems = [
        {
          Program: 1,
          To: 2,
          Date: 3,
          Approved: 3,
          Notes: 5
        }

      ];
      var tableContent =
        '<table id="deliverablesTable" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Program</strong></td>' +
        "<td><strong>To</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Approved</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Notes</strong></td>" +
        "</tr></thead><tbody>";

      for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
      }
      // Insert tableContent into the div to make sure it gets rendered
      $("#data").html(tableContent);
      // Make it a datatable now
      $("#deliverablesTable").DataTable();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes user the same code and find it working adding as answer

Answer (score 1):

I used code from above example, Please find code sample below. Ajax link is working when I was testing . this is an online mocking link .  you can create own mock request and test it if that ajax link is not working. I tested from above solution that it working fine .

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title><strong>X, DAR-Q, & Z Deliverables</strong></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <h4 class="text-center">X, DAR-Q, & Z Deliverables</h4>
        <table class = "display">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Program</th>
                <th>Deliverable</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Approved</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- RESERVE DIV FOR HOLDING THE DATA TABLE -->
    <div id="data" class="container">
    </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
 var objItems=[];
            $( document ).ready(function() {
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/1ee61ecd-d1ab-4ad8-8976-f94bcd296264",
            complete: function(data) {
              objItems=data.responseJSON.data;
              renderTable();
            }
        });
    });
        
function renderTable(){
     var tableContent =
        '<table id="deliverablesTable" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Program</strong></td>' +
        "<td><strong>To</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Approved</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Notes</strong></td>" +
        "</tr></thead><tbody>";

      for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
      }
      // Insert tableContent into the div to make sure it gets rendered
      $("#data").html(tableContent);
      // Make it a datatable now
      $("#deliverablesTable").DataTable();
}
      
      
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code just check ajax call is returning data.
[https://nightly.datatables.net/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('XDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes](https://nightly.datatables.net/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27XDeliverables%27)/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes)
put a fully qualified url in browser and check get request.